# Complex inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

How can I show this inequality $\sqrt{2}|z|\geq |\mathrm{Re} (z)|+|\mathrm{Im}(z)| $
please give me some hint. Which result is useful to show this. please help me out.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think about the geometric representation of complex numbers. Given a rectangle with sides $a = |\Im(z)|$ and $b = |\Re(z)|$, show that its diagonal is not shorter than $\frac{a+b}{\sqrt 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just write down $z$ as $a+bi$ with $a,b\in \mathbf R$. You can assume without loss of generality that $a,b\geq 0$. Then it's pretty much pure (elementary) algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=x+iy$  where x,y are real, $\sqrt2|z|=\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}$  which will be ≥ |x|+|y|  as Re(z)=x  and Im(z)=y,

iff $2(x^2+y^2)≥x^2+y^2+2|x||y|$  (as $|x|^2=x^2$  for real x)

iff $(|x|-|y|)^2≥0$  which is true as x,y are real